# ASP-style tags for Perl web development?

Tags: perl, programming-languages, language-features, language-design, perl-module

I feel like I'm traveling 10 years back in time by asking this, but...

Are there any modules, patches, or any "new" version of Perl (released in the last 10 years) to enable writing web-oriented Perl scripts using ASP-style tags?

e.g. from ASP/JSP

```
 some html <% some code %> more HTML
```

e.g. from PHP

```
 some html <? some code ?> more HTML
```

Please don't worry about "why" I'm asking this... It's related to programming language research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. Check out [Mason](http://www.masonhq.com/).

You can install it from CPAN with `cpan -i HTML::Mason`.

There's also [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/), which makes it a bit easier to separate your template and logic code, but allows a lot of the same constructs.

Answer (score 4):

[`Markup::Perl`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Markup::Perl) gets you pretty close to PHP/ASP style programming in Perl.

```
  # don't write this...
  print "Content-type: text/html;\n\n";
  print "<html>\n<body>\n";
  print "<p>\nYour \"lucky number\" is\n";
  print "<i>", int rand 10, "</i>\n</p>\n";
  print "</body>\n</html>\n";

  # write this instead...
  use Markup::Perl;
  <html>
  <body>
  <p>
  Your "lucky number" is
  <i><perl> print int rand 10 </perl></i>
  </p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Google `"PerlHP"` for the sordid history of `Markup::Perl

Answer (score 4):

[Embperl](http://perl.apache.org/embperl/pod/list/Features.htm) does support ASP style tags.

Answer (score 3):

There's [Apache::ASP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Apache::ASP) and [Apache2::ASP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Apache2::ASP)